# What does fgets() reads?

Tags: c, windows, unix, newline, fgets

I have to migrate a program from UNIX to Windows. The program is about getting data from serial port. In original UNIX machine that is receiving it, it reads as:

```
char   my_buffer_a[200];

memset(my_buffer_a, '\0', sizeof(my_buffer_a));

if (fgets(my_buffer_a, sizeof(my_buffer_a), file_p))
{
    n = sscanf("%d\t%d\t...%d\n0x0A", 
               my_record.field1, my_record.field2, ...)
    ....
}
```

I know that fgets() will read until a EOF or a newline character. That means in my_buffer_a, I would expect the '\n' at the end. Yet to my suprise, there is ***also*** ***0x0A***! (Does that mean ***TWO*** newline characters?) What is going on here?

Another thing I worry is in the definition of newline character in Unix and Windows. They are not the same in Unix and in Windows. I mean after I convert, when I do `sscanf`, I will have to do `sscanf("%d\t%d\t...%d\r\n` (or `sscanf(%d\t%d\t...%d\r0x0D\n0x0A` while keeping that wierd logic)?

Comment: Could you actually be unaware that `0x0a` is the ASCII encoding for `'\n'` (and `0x0d` the encoding for `'\r'`)? And that Windows uses `'\r\n'` for text file line endings, while Unix uses `'\n'` only? Could you really be that unaware of text basics?

Comment: Yes I have already checked that what `0x0A` and `0x0D` mean. As I state in the code (written by someone else), the `sscanf` ends with `\n0X0A`. That means ***TWO*** newline characters in the original UNIX program. Does that imply the fgets() takes in two newline characters?

Comment: Print the input string in hexadecimal, and check your assumptions. Rule of thumb: Standard functions are not broken. Documentation of standard functions is not broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A newline in a scanf format string does NOT specifically look for a newline in the input -- it just skips whitespace (any whitespace).  The same for tab characters.  In addition, *most* scanf format specifiers (everything except `%c` and `%[`) skip whitespace.  So in general:

- you should *never* use `\t`, `\r` or `\n` in a format string (except within `%[`..`]`), as it will just confuse people.  Use a space instead, which does the same thing
- you should avoid using redundant spaces in the format string, because they don't anything and will just confuse people.

So with the above, your `sscanf` call becomes:

```
sscanf("%d%d ...%d 0x0A",
```

Making it clear that this reads two numbers, followed by three periods, followed by another number, and finally the string `0x0A` (4 characters).  There may be any whitespace between any of those 6 things (or not), and it will be ignored.

As far as windows vs Unix is concerned, with Windows, there will be extra carriage return (`\r`) characters at the end of lines.  But these are just whitespace, and so will be skipped by `scanf` just like any other whitespace.  So you can just ignore them.

Comment: Finally someone can point out the confusion I have. Thank you for 'aware' of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is "going on". Please [read the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), which clearly states:

> If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

The difference in line number encoding shouldn't matter, they're both whitespace after all and thus skipped by `sscanf()` in many cases.

Comment: But there are two newline character! The `sscanf()` ends with `\n0x0A`. I expect there is only one newline character!

Comment: @user3454439 Exactly how do you know that there are two newline characters? Your `sscanf()` line of reasoning is faulty for two reasons: 1) `0x0A` does not mean newline in a `scanf` format string, it means a sequence of four ASCII characters, `0x0A`. To specify a newline, you'd use `\x0A`, or simply `\n`. 2) `sscanf()` processes as much of the format string as it can and returns the number of items processed. If the string doesn't really end with `0x0A`, `sscanf` won't care, it will return the number of successfully converted items.

Comment: @user4815162342: Thanks. Your comment is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A file saved in windows, will \r\n at the end of each file.
In linux the end of file is having only \n.

Comment: `sizeof(my_buffer_a)` is actually 200 bytes.